# Mysql faster INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, insert

Ok, I've got about 175k INSERT statements, pretty big INSERT statements, example:

```
INSERT INTO `gast` (`ID`,`Identiteitskaartnummer`,`Naam`,`Voornaam`,`Adres`,`Postcode`,`Stad`,`Land`,`Tel`,`Gsm`,`Fax`,`Email`,`Creditcardnummer`) VALUES ('100001','5121-1131-6328-9416','Cameron','Rhoda','Ap #192-1541 Velit Rd.','54398','Catskill','Bermuda','1-321-643-8255','(120) 502-0360','1 48 428 3971-3704','tempor@justo.org','8378-3645-3748-8446');
```

(Disregard the fact this is in Dutch). All the data is completely random.

I've got to do this about 3 to 4 times. Querying 100k INSERT statements takes about an hour on my PC. Is there any way to do this faster without altering the INSERT statements? I'm using MySQL Workbench. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I've tried everything suggested so far. Using only one INSERT but multiple VALUES gives me an error that the INSERT statement is too big. Disabling the indexes before inserting doesn't improve performance either.

I've also tried loading an sql file through command line, but that doesn't do anything either...

Insert performance varies from 0.015s to 0.032s per INSERT.

Comment: Remove the indexes on the table(s) before the inserts will drastically improve the performance

Comment: This taking an hour probably means that you are doing something wrong. Wrap a transaction around it and use parameterized SQL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INSERT all of the data into one table - the table you're going to reseed your database with - and then issue an INSERT SELECT statement because it will then execute it as a batch instead of 175K different statements.

Also, when you reseed your database with the INSERT SELECT statement, turn off contraints on the target table `ALTER TABLE yourtablename DISABLE KEYS` and then turn them back on afterwards `ALTER TABLE yourtablename ENABLE KEYS`.

I would also personally build a [covering index](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/) on the seed data table because then it wouldn't have to read a data page.

Comment: @Matthias Yes, but you only have to do that once, and then you will reseed your database from that table going forward. If you don't want to go down that road then you can try just using the second piece of my recommendation, turning off constraints, and perform all 175K INSERT statements that way. Either way, the issue is that you're asking the server to perform 175K INSERT statements and likely on a machine that wasn't built for that.

Comment: Disabling the keys doesn't really give me an increased performance. It stays the same.

Comment: @Matthias Okay, then there must not be that many keys on the table. I would say then at this point the issue is that you're PC is simply not capable of handling the load. Have you tried the same set of statements on a **test** or **production** server? If you need to do this more frequently consider trying my entire recommendation, it will take a while the first time, but the following iterations will be **much** shorter.

Comment: I'm running this on a Windows 7 64-bit SP1 machine with an Intel Core2 Quac Q9000 @ 2.0Ghz, 4Gb RAM. It's a local MySQL and I have to do this because of a school assignment. (Create a database, he said. Fill it with a few 100k rows of data, he said...)

I'm not going to do this frequently, it's a one time thing, but it's bugging me I have to sit here all day, waiting for some insert statements to execute.

Comment: @Matthias - based on that I would say the issue is that you're machine is simply not built for this type of processing. If you don't have to do it multiple times then do it once and forget about it, you're spending more time trying to optimize a one-time process than it would take to just do it one time.

Answer (score 1):

Just use one statement

```
INSERT INTO `gast` 

    (`ID`,`Identiteitskaartnummer`,`Naam`,`Voornaam`,`Adres`,`Postcode`,`Stad`,`Land`,`Tel`,`Gsm`,`Fax`,`Email`,`Creditcardnummer`) 
    VALUES 
    ('100001','5121-1131-6328-9416','Cameron','Rhoda','Ap #192-1541 Velit Rd.','54398','Catskill','Bermuda','1-321-643-8255','(120) 502-0360','1 48 428 3971-3704','tempor@justo.org','8378-3645-3748-8446'),
    ('100002','5121-1131-6328-9416','Cameron','Rhoda','Ap #192-1541 Velit Rd.','54398','Catskill','Bermuda','1-321-643-8255','(120) 502-0360','1 48 428 3971-3704','tempor@justo.org','8378-3645-3748-8446')
```

etc etc....

Maybe you should do 10000 a time instead of all 175k

Comment: Too bad:

Error Code: 1153. Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

Also: "Without editing the INSERT statements."

Comment: What are you actually doing? Inserting data from one table to another?

Comment: Generating a bunch of INSERT statements with random data and then inserting those.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to save the data to a text file then load the data in using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Its probably not as nice but it'll be much faster

Answer (score 1):

Put all your data in a csv file and user load data infile FILENAME into table TABLE
It wont take more than a minute
If you want to do it with insert it is better to use a single insert sending several rows at a time