# Inserting Unique 1 Million records in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am using PHP and MySQL to insert unique records in database. I have to insert 1 Million unique records.

Here is what I am currently doing:

1) Table1 holds records. Table1 has only 1 Column which has been defined as primary. Initially Table1 is empty.

2) Random Numerical String (RNS) is generated (approx. length 18) in PHP e.g. 834875609567689789

3) RNS is checked in Table1.

4) If it doesn't exist in Table1 then it is inserted in Table1 & Table2 (for Table2 some random string e.g XYZ is appended to RNS like 834875609567689789XYZ and inserted into Table2).

5) Table2 has only 1 Column which has been defined as primary.

6) I am running a loop of 100 RNS in PHP (comparing 1 RNS at each time Steps 3,4) to do above steps. Each loop of 100 is taking 20-25 seconds.

How this can be done faster?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql faster INSERT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794635/mysql-faster-insert)

Answer (score 0):

you can make it faster by inserting multiple rows at a time instead of running a new query for each of them. You may have to adjust the way PHP is processing the data, but if you can run a single query like this instead of a bunch of them, it will be much faster.

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
(val1, val2, val3),
(val1, val2, val3),
(val1, val2, val3),
(val1, val2, val3)
```

Comment: Same solution I have gone through for some other question. This can be done for Table2 insertion only (where I can get Unique records from a Loop of 100 that were inserted in Table1 using PHP and then using this method insert them in Table2). But how to insert and check for Table1 first?

Comment: if you post your code i'd be happy to change it for you but i'm not gonna blindly rewrite the whole thing

Comment: basically, create placeholder arrays, instead of populating the tables, populate the arrays. then at the bottom, do a single insert for each table using the arrays of data you already processed. that cuts you down to three querys.

Comment: I am thinking of using placeholder array now. Understood the concept. So the process would be as follows: 1) Get 100 Random Strings. 2) Check for each RNS in Table1 (100 Query Lookups). 3) RNS which are unique, add them to Placeholder Array 1 (PA1) & Placeholder Array2 (PA2). 4) Insert PA1 to Table1 (1 Insert statement). 5) Insert PA2 to Table2 (1 Insert Statement). Please correct if some step is wrong.

Comment: assuming your table doesn't have a bazillion rows it would be much easier and more efficient to just select all the rns numbers in the table in a single query at the begining and do your checks against that.

Answer (score 0):

First create a table with new RNS values - `rns_list`.  Do batched inserts of 1000.  Then do steps 3 & 4 en masse:

Do 1000 rows at a time, in 3 SQLs:

```
# Get rid of dups (very rare if you have a good random number generator)
DELETE FROM rns_list
    FROM rns_list
    JOIN table1  ON rns_list.rns = table1.rns;
# You will need an index starting with rns on table1.
# Now you have perhaps slightly less than 1000,
# so tally the count somewhere (assuming you need exactly 1 million)
# Now do the two inserts:
INSERT INTO table1  SELECT * FROM rns_list;
INSERT INTO table2  SELECT CONCAT(rns, 'XYZ') FROM rns_list;
```

Repeat until you have done a million.

Batched operations (such as each of these) is typically 10x faster than row-by-row.